# How To Create Segments In A Circle Using HTML5 & CSS3

Tags: javascript, html, css

It is possible to create a segments inside the circle on the basis of input . I am trying to represent the fraction value in the form of circle by creating the segments for example :-

there is a div

```
<div class="circle">
</div>

    circle has a width of 150px & height as well now with a border radius of 50%;
```

i want to take input value of numerator and denominator display the number of segments in the circle div

for example like this

[image]

Comment: Do you want to do this with the div and CSS? Or would have you looked at drawing on a canvas?

Comment: If you are up for some quirky css and don't need to support too many legacy browsers - https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2015/07/designing-simple-pie-charts-with-css/

Comment: @NicholasRobinson it doesnot matter but on the basis of input i want to develop some thing like this which is given in the picture

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are going to be dealing with possibly complex angles, I would recommend that you use a `canvas`. Here is an example of how you can achieve what you are looking for:

```js
//Getting the context for the canvas
var canvas = document.getElementById('fraction');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

var x = 80; // X coordinate for the position of the segment
var y = 80; // Y coordinate for the position of the segment
var radius = 75; // Radius of the circle

// This is what you will be changing
// Maybe get these values from a function that pulls the numbers from an input box
var numerator = 1;
var denominator = 4;
var fraction = numerator / denominator; // The angle that will be drawn

// For plotting the segments
var startAngle = Math.PI;
var endAngle = (1 + (2 * fraction)) * startAngle;

// If the circle is draw clockwise or anti-clockwise
// Setting this to true will draw the inverse of the angle
var drawClockwise = false;

// Drawing the segment
context.beginPath();
context.arc(x, y, radius, startAngle, endAngle, drawClockwise);
context.lineTo(x, y);
context.closePath();
context.fillStyle = 'yellow';
context.fill();

//***************** Edit *******************

// This will add the circle outline around the segment
context.beginPath();
context.arc(x, y, radius, 0, Math.PI * 2, drawClockwise);
context.closePath();
context.strokeStyle = '#000';
context.stroke();
```

```html
<div>
  <canvas id="fraction" width="200" height="200"></canvas>
</div>
```

In the code above you can play with the variables, but the main variables that you will be interested in are `numerator`, `denominator` and `fraction`. These make up the fraction that you mentioned above and are used to draw the correct segment.

You can also play with the other variables to change the size and position of the shape, the direction that it is drawn in. You are not limited to these though, there are many other things that you can change!

[Here](http://blog.michelledinan.com/02/2012/html5-canvas-drawing-simple-shapes/#circles) is an example of drawing circles and segments onto the canvas, [here](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/tutorials/html5-canvas-semicircles/) is an example of the how to set and change the colour and outline of the shape and [here](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_canvas.asp) is an introduction to canvas in general.

I hope this helps!

Good luck :)